# Field and storage settings on base fields

Tags: 8, entities

I am rewriting my config fields (Field API fields) into base fields and I am unsure about one thing: settings.

Base fields have the `setSettings()` method, which I presume is equivalent of field instance settings. Then, there is `getFieldStorageDefinition()->setSettings()`, which I presume is equivalent of storage settings.
When I look at the entity reference item and the user ID field used by the node entity, the user ID field calls `setSetting('target_type', 'user')`, which is storage setting and not instance setting. Do I get these two wrong? What is going on?

[`Node::baseFieldDefinitions()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Entity%21Node.php/function/Node%3A%3AbaseFieldDefinitions/8.9.x) contains the following code.

```php
$fields['uid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
  ->setLabel(t('Authored by'))
  ->setDescription(t('The username of the content author.'))
  ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'user')
```

[`EntityReferenceItem::defaultStorageSettings()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Field%21Plugin%21Field%21FieldType%21EntityReferenceItem.php/function/EntityReferenceItem%3A%3AdefaultStorageSettings/8.9.x) contains the following code.

```php
return [
  'target_type' => \Drupal::moduleHandler()->moduleExists('node') ? 'node' : 'user',
] + parent::defaultStorageSettings();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base field definition implements the FieldDefinitionInterface and the FieldStorageDefinitionInterface, so it can act like a form API field, though it's not managed by the field module.

So the base field definition contains the settings of both, which you can see how the default values are set in `BaseFieldDefinition::create()`:

```
  public static function create($type) {
    ...
    $default_settings = $field_type_manager->getDefaultStorageSettings($type) + $field_type_manager->getDefaultFieldSettings($type);
    $field_definition->itemDefinition->setSettings($default_settings);
    return $field_definition;
  }
```